# Object length in javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

is there any way in typescript by which I can get length of an object:

Something like this:

say I have an object:

```
public customer:any={
     "name":"Bhushan",
     "eid":"879546",
     "dept":"IT"
}
```

Now I am trying to get its length in typescript.

ie. when I am doing `customer.length()`, I should be able to get value 3 as it has 3 elements.

I tried `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(customer.value)` but its returning 2 whereas I have 3 elements in my object.

any inputs?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
Object.keys(customer).length
```

Answer (score 15):

```
Object.keys(this.customer).length
```